# Easier way to switch between Texture Paint Brush Types

Tags: texture-painting

In Blender2.9,`clicking on brush type icon on the left tools menu doesn't switch between brush types`.

There is a roundabout way shown in video below but this ends up creating a lot of spare brushes.

What is the best way to switch between brush types?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a bug or maybe some shortcut has been overriden. Have you tried resetting the setting to factory ?

Comment: Did you open your sidebar?  Letter N or Letter T.

Comment: There seems to be a bug with this particular blend file. On recreating the issue in a fresh blend file, the brush switching happens fine.